# Delete row containing #N/A

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to delete rows from a table where a value within that row is #N/A

```vb
Sub remove_na()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim r As Variant
Dim i As Variant

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each i In Range("A1:A" & r)
    If i = "#N/A" Then i.EntireRow.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

I get a Type Mismatch error on the IF statement. I tried using WHILE loops as well as FOR. The same issue occurred.

An example of the data being processed is columns of data (a few hundred records):

```
#N/A        #N/A
#N/A        #N/A
#N/A        #N/A
#N/A        #N/A
#N/A        #N/A
#N/A        #N/A
#N/A        #N/A
456699.512  6523052.64
456699.512  6523052.64
456699.512  6523052.64
456699.512  6523052.64
456699.512  6523052.64
```

Comment: do yo have some blank rows in between the data rows?

Comment: I do not. It is a single block of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub remove_na()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim r As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

r = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = r To 1 Step -1
    If IsError(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Edited to improve answer

Comment: Thank you. has half solved the issue. However, it is not deleting all of the error rows. I have checked that r is returning the same value as rows in my table.

Comment: @JKRH - how about now?

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you so much, I have been suffering over that for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`IsError()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.iserror) to evaluate if the cell contains the `#N/A` error within your `If...Then` statement.

Like so:

```
If IsError(i.Value) Then
    i.EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Note: Not tested due to lack of excel on this workstation.

Comment: That was a good start, but it has only deleted about half the error messages. For some reason, the xlUp is not long enough to do the entire data set.

Comment: @JKRH I should have added, work your loop backwards from bottom to top, otherwise it will skip rows as it deletes one the next move up (but your loop increments too). Ill update once home but you can google anout a billion posts of how to do that if you need to.